# Como iterar un Array() de manera Dinámica

Tags: array, iteraciones

Tengo un problema cuando quiero iterar un array de manera dinámica con otro array

```
var str = Array();
str[0]= "foo";
str[1]= "x";
console.log(str); // ["foo", "x"]
var arr = Array();
arr.foo = "Example Text";
arr.x = "Example Text 2"
console.log(arr) //[foo: "Example Text", x: "Example Text 2"]
for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(arr.str[i]);
}
```

Error:'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at :8:21'

Comment: Has un console.log() de tus arreglos y muestra que trae cada uno

Comment: Listo agregue los console.log()

Comment: Tu arreglo `arr` no tiene un índice o propiedad que sea `1` si tiene, sin embargo, la propiedad `foo` y la propiedad `x`

Comment: quiero usar lo que esta en str para acceder directamente a las propiedades de arr directamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que acceder es el valor `i` de tu primer arreglo, el cual te regresa la llave que estás buscando en tu segundo arreglo `arr['foo'], arr['x']`

```js
var str = Array();
str[0]= "foo";
str[1]= "x";

var arr = Array();
arr.foo = "Example Text";
arr.x = "Example Text 2";

for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(arr[str[i]]);
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias!, era exactamente lo que necesitaba.